# How to Push AJAX array response into an js array

Tags: jquery

**On a AjAX call , i am getting data**

```
success : function(data){
               alert(data);
         }
```

**This is the result of that alert**

```
[/files/1.jpg,/files/2.jpg,/files/3.jpg]
```

**I want to push this result into a javascript array**

```
 var outputdata = [];
```

Where the array outputdata should look like

```
 var outputdata = [/files/1.jpg,/files/2.jpg,/files/3.jpg];
```

I tried this way

```
success : function(data){
               alert(data);
outputdata.push(data);

         }
```

Updated Part

I tried with yours as wel as with this

```
success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(i) {

                    outputdata.push(data[i]);
                });
                alert(outputdata);

                outputdata.forEach(function (element) {

                      content = "<div><a href='#'><img src=" + element + "   /></a></div>";
                     $("#container").append(content);
                    });

            }
```

[image]

The initial alert data is fine (I mean initial means )

```
success: function(data) {

             alert(data);

                $.each(data, function(i) {

                    outputdata.push(data[i]);
                });
                alert(outputdata);
```

See the Picture of initial alert

[image]

Comment: Super-classy taskbar you've got there.

Comment: You might want to be sure and clear your browser history before your mom gets home.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you do that?
*data* is already an array and you can call the elements by

```
data[i]
```

Or is it a data string that is returned from you ajax call?
Than you need to parse it first, like

```
var your_data = JSON.parse(data);
```

and can call it by

```
your_data[i]
```

Anyway, looping an array would look like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i) {
        outputdata[i] = data[i];
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks , i tried  either way but not working , please see the updated question

Comment: I am more then confused by your screenshot now.